# How to auto add a value after user text field input

Tags: php, html, forms

How do I add an auto value after a user adds text to an input in a text/email field.
For example, the user enters their cell phone number and a custom @domain.com is entered after user input.
Please see code below:

```
<div class="email">
    <input class="gift_receiver_email" type="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Email address', WC_SC_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>..." name="gift_receiver_email[0][0]" value="" />
</div>
```

Note: I am not referring to the set value when user sees the field (example value="text displayed") and should set the function to only run when a minimum  of 10 characters is entered by the user

Comment: You could use 'onBlur' to call a javascript function. This will mean that once the user has moved their cursor from the textbox, the javascript will be called.

Comment: The examples below work perfectly although if a user go's back to edit the field or remove the text the function stacks as mentioned by some users below. Is it possible to set the function to only run when a minumum and maximum of 10 characters is entered by the user.

Comment: @Walter People gave JS/jQuery answers where the question doesn't hold any of the tags. Are you still open to accept possible solutions using those (other) languages besides PHP? Second question; someone added the "php" tag; is that what you're looking for, or any language (mentioned)?

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I am open to hooking in other languages to resolve this. I cant change my base code though. Please feel free to edit the question with the languages you think will be best. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Walter Thing is that, if people disable JS which they can, answers offering JS/jQuery (and ajax) will not work. Personally, if JS is to be used, then a serverside method should be used at the same time. I rarely use JS, only for fancy stuff, eye candy for example. The choice is yours if you want me to edit the tags. However, you might like to edit your question to contain specifics, just so everyone knows what to expect.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I have found my answer below but you are making very valid points and will take this into consideration in future.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Consider accepting the answer that worked best in order to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **Simplest Example**

```js
function addDefault(tag)
{
  
  if(tag.value.length != 10) //to check if characters length is not 10
  return; //exit the function
  tag.value += '_someValue';

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onblur="addDefault(this)">
```

Comment: This work perfectly although if a user go's back to edit the field or remove the text the function stacks as mentioned by some users below. Is it possible to set the function to only run when a minumum and maximum of 10 characters is entered by the user.

Comment: @Walter yes it is possible... simple we need to add a condition like this
`if(this.value.length != 10) return;`

Comment: Do you mind adding the condition into your code, I keep getting an error. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, im getting the following error when I run the snippet "{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 16,
  "colno": 17
} " thanks for all your help thus far

Comment: Works like a charm thank you very much @matee gojra. This is the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="gift_receiver_email" class="gift_receiver_email" type="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Email address', WC_SC_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>..." name="gift_receiver_email[0][0]" value="" /

var gift_receiver_email = document.getElementById("gift_receiver_email");
gift_receiver_email.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
    var value = event.target.style.background = "";   
    value += '@domain.com';
    gift_receiver_email.value = val(value);  
}, true);
```

Comment: in question use of JQuery is not mentioned

Comment: @MateeGojra Same thing goes for all of the other answers (so far) which offer a JS method.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment. You can use 'onBlur' to call a javascript function which will give the illusion of an automatic call. Another alternative would be to use onChange however I would suggest against this as this will call the javascript function EVERY time the user enters a character

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** `onChange` is more better than `onBlur` and updated my answer accordingly.

---

**Using `onChange`:**

```js
function updateInput(inputElm) {  
  inputElm.value = inputElm.value+'@domain.com';
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
    <input class="gift_receiver_email" type="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Email address', WC_SC_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>..." name="gift_receiver_email[0][0]" value="" onchange="updateInput(this)"/>
</div>
```

**Using `onBlur`:**

```js
function updateInput(inputElm) {  
  inputElm.value = inputElm.value+'@domain.com';
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
    <input class="gift_receiver_email" type="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Email address', WC_SC_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>..." name="gift_receiver_email[0][0]" value="" onblur="updateInput(this)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest against using onChange in this case however as the function will get called every time the user enters a character

Comment: The examples work perfectly although if a user go's back to edit the field or remove the text the function stacks as mentioned by some users below. Is it possible to set the function to only run when a minumum and maximum of 10 characters is entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

use the onchange event.
blur event is fired everytime you focus and leave the input text.

change event is fired only when its content changes. (browser do the work for you)

in either case, you have to check to not stack with '+ @domain.com' like this:
test@domain.com@domain.com.

this is a simple task to solve, i can leave it to you.